# Selenium ActionChains key commands enacting key shortcut?

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook, keyboard, apscheduler

I have a Python program that uses APScheduler and Selenium to automate webscraping. Basically it scrapes a particular website once every hour, and then schedules certain more detailed scrapes to happen at intervals.

The issue is that while I want to start the scraper, and then be free to use my computer for other work, Selenium will then automatically focus on the opened chrome tabs whenever a new scrape is started by APScheduler. Because of this, I am trying to find a way to have the new chrome windows open - but I don't have to focus on them. I've already tried headless and phantomJS, but the site is dynamically generated so these don't really work.

My current solution is to open the new window, minimise it, and then immediately shift back to the old window. To do this I want to perform a keyboard shortcut using ActionChains. I currently have this test code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
ActionChains(driver).key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
```

Currently this code does nothing however. Is there anyway to fix this? I am using Jupyter Notebook and I am on a mac for reference.

*NOTE: this code is being run apart from the main program, I am just using it to test if the script will work.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. You never .perform() it.

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(Keys.RIGHT).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```